# Create a post as a user and assign it to a group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

In my rails application I have made three models, User, Group and Post.
I am trying to make it so that @post.group is equal to @group.id
The post is posted from a render inside of the group#show controller and then redirects itself to the post#create controller. How do I set the @post.group to @group.id?

GroupsController

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_group, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @groups = Group.all
    respond_with(@groups)
  end

  def show
    @group_id = @group.id
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def new
    @group = Group.new
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    @group.save
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def update
    @group.update(group_params)
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def destroy
    @group.destroy
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  private
    def set_group
      @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    end

    def group_params
      params.require(:group).permit(:name, :description, :motto, :usercount, :group, :id, :groupid)
    end
end
```

PostsController

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_with(@posts)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post.group = @group_id
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def update
    @post.update(post_params)
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_group
      @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:body, :group, :id)
    end

    def group_params
      params.require(:group).permit(:id, :groupid, :group)
    end
end
```

PostModel

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end
```

GroupsModel

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

The current code that I have returns the error `undefined method`group=' for nil:NilClass`
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `@post.group = @group_id` the `@group_id` is `nil`, because you don't set it

Answer (score 0):

You should start from creating `Post` instance, because you don't do this. I would do it like this:

```
def create
  @post = @group.posts.build(post_params)
  if @post.save
    # handle success
  else
    # handle error
  end
end
```

What's more, you should set `before_action :set_group` in your `PostsController`.

Comment: What controller should that be in?

Comment: BTW, i tested it in post controller and it said undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @coreypizzle it should be in `PostsController`. It says this because you should have `before_action :set_group` in your `PostsController`.

Comment: That spits out the error `Couldn't find Group without an ID`

Comment: Use nested resources then. And go through any basic Rails tutorial.

Comment: I agree with @MarekLipka, you're trying to deviate from the rails conventions, which even if you achieved successfully, will come back and be a pain in the future when you change/add new functionality to your website.